# How to configure liquibase not to include file path or name for calculating checksum?

Tags: liquibase

I found that liquibase uses the full path of the change log file to calculate the checksum.

This behavior restricts to modify change log file names and tries to reapply the change sets again once renamed the file.

Is there a way to configure liquibase to use only the changelog id to 
calculate cuecksum?

Please provide your valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 14):

Use the attribute [`logicalFilePath`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html) of the `databaseChangeLog` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Upstream developers recommend to use `logicalFilePath` and suggest to perform direct update on `DATABASECHANGELOG.FILENAME` column:

- https://forum.liquibase.org/t/why-does-the-change-log-contain-the-file-name/481

to fix broken entries with full paths.

If you set hashes `DATABASECHANGELOG.MD5SUM` to `null` that triggers hashes recalculation on next LiquiBase run. It is necessary as hash algorithm includes moving parts too into the result.

Answer (score 5):

One really similar issue- you may just want to ignore the portion of the path before the `changelog-master.xml` file. In my scenario, I've checked out a project in `C:\DEV\workspace` and my colleague has the project checked out in `C:\another_folder\TheWorkspace`.

I'd recommend reading through http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/changeset-uniqueness-causing-issues-with-branched-releases-overlapped-changes-not-allowed-in-different-files first.

Like others have suggested, you'll want the `logicalFilePath` property set on the `<databaseChangeLog>` element.

You'll also need to specify the `changeLogFile` property in a certain way when calling liquibase. I'm calling it from the command line. If you specify an absolute or relative path to the `changeLogFile` **without** the classpath, like this, it will include the whole path in the DATABASECHANGELOG table:

```
liquibase.bat ^
--changeLogFile=C:\DEV\more\folders\schema\changelog-master.xml ^
...
```

then liquibase will break if you move your migrations to any folder other than that one listed above. To fix it (and ensure that other developers can use whatever workspace location they want), you need to reference the `changelogFile` from the classpath:

```
liquibase.bat ^
--classpath=C:\DEV\more\folders ^
--changeLogFile=schema/changelog-master.xml ^
...
```

The first way, my DATABASECHANGELOG table had FILENAME values (I might have the slash backwards) like

```
C:\DEV\more\folders\schema\subfolder\script.sql
```

The second way, my DATABASECHANGELOG table has FILENAME values like

```
subfolder/script.sql
```

I'm content to go with filenames like that. Each developer can run liquibase from whatever folder they want. If we decide we want to rename or move an individual SQL file later on, then we can specify the old value in the `logicalFilePath` property of the `<changeSet>` element.

For reference, my `changelog-master.xml` just consists of elements like

```
<include file="subfolder/script.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem and found solution below.

If you are using liquibase `sql format` then simply put below in your sql file:

`--liquibase formatted sql logicalFilePath:<relative SQL file path like(liquibase/changes.sql)>`

If you are using liquibase `xml format` then simply put below in your xml file:

```
<databaseChangeLog logicalFilePath=relative XML file path like(liquibase/changes.xml)" ...>
...
</databaseChangeLog>
```

After adding above `logicalFilePath` attribute, run the liquibase `update` command.
It will put `relative file path` whatever you put in `logicalFilePath` in `FILENAME` column of table `DATABASECHANGELOG`