# In Liquibase, how can logicalFilePath be specified in a YAML change log?

Tags: yaml, liquibase

I want to change the logical file path to be a fixed string as described in [Liquibase: How to disable FILENAME column check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959755/liquibase-how-to-disable-filename-column-check/19959756#19959756). I want to apply it to all change sets without having to specify it in every one. It seems the change log, that groups change sets, permits this [according to the documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html). However, the documentation always refers to *tags* and *attributes*, as if the change log is in XML format. In case my change log is in YAML format, how can I specify the `logicalFilePath` attribute?

Answer (score 4):

`logicalFilePath` could indeed be added on a `databaseChangeLog` level.

So your changeLog could look like this:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - logicalFilePath: your_path_here
    - changeSet:
        id: foo
        author: bar
        changes:
            - your changes here
```

Check out Liquibase tests in [github](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/test/resources/liquibase/parser/core/yaml/logicalPathChangeLog.yaml)